# Property 'select' does not exist on type 'Web'

Tags: spfx, typescript

I'm trying to use @pnp/sp with SPFx like shown on [pnp GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/dev/packages/sp/docs/index.md#getting-started-sharepoint-framework) page:

```
sp.web.select("Title").get().then(w => {
    console.log("title: " + w.Title);
});
```

When compiling the following TypeScript error is thrown: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'Web'

Comment: Which version of pnp js you are using? try installing it again using `npm i @pnp/sp`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import { sp, Web, IWeb } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

const web = await sp.web();
console.log(web.Title);
console.log(web.Id);
```

Be sure that you installed the correct libraries